# Upload directory path to database for multiple files

Tags: flask, directory, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

I am using `flask-admin`, so I can add entries to the database without having to interact with it directly. I can currently save the name of one image file with my code. I would like to save the name of the directory instead so I can have multiple images under a folder.

```
base_path = op.join(op.dirname(__file__), 'static/pictures')

class listingsModelView(ModelView) :
# ModelView Functionality        
page_size = 20

form_columns = ['Location', 'City', 'State', 'Zip',
                'Price', 'Bedroom', 'Bathroom', 'SquareFeet',
                'Description', 'Pictures']
column_labels = dict(Location="Street Address", City='City', State='State',
                     Zip='Zip Code', Price='Price', Bedroom='Bedroom', Bathroom='Bathroom',
                     SquareFeet='Square Feet', Description='Description', Pictures='Pictures')

form_overrides = dict(Pictures=FileUploadField)
form_args = {
    'Pictures': {
        'label': 'File',
        'base_path': base_path,
        'allow_overwrite': True
    }
}
```

is there any way I can modify what I currently have to store a directory path instead of a single file name?